# Ubuntu Server 22.04,3 not detecting Dell Perc H310 Mirror

Tags: 22.04, hardware, raid

U have a Dell T430 server with a PERC H310 installed.
It has 2 x Samsung Evo 870's installed and setup in a Raid1 config.

The Problem is, Ubuntu Server 22.04,3 doesnt see the controller or raid1.
According to posts on askubuntu the H310 is supported

Can any advice whats going on?

[image: Virtual Disk config]

[image: Control Info]

[image: Controller properties]

[image: Virtual Disk group]

UPDATE:
I noticed I had this error when booting the installer, So I updated the firmwares for the Controller and dell t430 server to the latest, sadly it still didnt work
[image]

Comment: Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Read `man journalctl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out. The bios needed to be in UEFI mode

Comment: Interesting.  Maybe it will be usefull to summarize how you achieved to put BIOS in UEFI mode, for future reference.

Comment: Upon starting the computer up, you are given options at the beginning to "enter BIOS" are something along those lines. press which ever key it tells you to press. When the BIOS setup screen appears you will have to navigate around as every bios interface is different till you find the boot options where you have a choice than contains "BIOS" and "UEFI" modes. IMO if you dont know about the BIOS is you wont get very far with linux servers and RAID controllers etc...